# what is the proper way to filter/change some content after a page loads with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Due to limitations, I can only solve this from front-end (javascript/HTML). I am waiting for a widget on my page (async, websocket), after it loads it will display some text in different divs/labels. I need to search this labels for some string and then replace it with an adequate one. This is just a temporary fix, the issue will be fixed from back-end. So what would be a quick and proper way to wait for this element to be loaded and then search/replace this elements?

PS: I already know I can search for them with jquery selectors, I just wanna know what approach to take and where it's better to place the code or if applying a common solution would be best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is too general and can't be answered in its current form. " Waiting for a widget" implies that you need to attach an event handler to something or write some kind of "onload" callback. But it's impossible to provide any detail without more info about the widget and how it is invoked.

Comment: What do you mean by -- " I just wanna know what approach to take and where it's better to place the code or if applying a common solution would be best?" You seem to have said that you need to do this in "(javascript/HTML)" and I'm totally confused by what you mean by "common solution" from your example. Please clarify?

Comment: We don’t even know whether your “widget” supports any type of events, so in worst case you’d simply have to try and see if the content is “there yet” using a timer interval. And asking for the “best solution” is kinda nonsense, when you already seem to be aware that fixing this in the back end _is_ what ultimately needs to be done – so might as well do that _now_ instead of investing in client-side workarounds that are only gonna get scrapped again eventually.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was too vague with this. My widget does not support events for the moment, I think I will end up doing what CBroe suggests.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("idoftext").innerHTML = "Text changed!";
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help. 
Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers.